# Graph theory: verification of number of elements

Tags: graph-theory

Hello and thanks for your time reading this. I'm hoping this is the right place to ask this question.

I am just about to finish a summer internship before my final year at uni. The internship involved producing a tool to visualise metabolic flux changes in heart muscle cells. I am fairly new to programming and it's best to say my maths knowledge is rusty. Please excuse if something seems off.

My dataset contains 4200 reactions involving 2980 compounds which can act as reactants or products in the reactions. I've chosen a nodes and edges graph to show different compounds as nodes and reactions as edges. Some compounds can be reactants in one reaction but be a product in another one. I try to avoid duplications to simulate a flow. Some reactions do not have products. A compound can only occur once in a reaction.

I need a way to verify that I have the correct number of edges. What I've been trying to do so far is compare the number of edges I generate to the number of times any compound occurs in any reaction. The two numbers are of a similar magnitude but never equal which makes me think my original code might be repeating something or not taking something into account. I also had to make what I call "pseudo nodes" because some reactions have multiple reactants/products. Pseudo nodes are invisible in the final rendering and just serve as locations for multiple reactants/products to join up/separate before/after a reaction has happened.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
for every reaction in all_reactions: 
  for every reactant in the reaction:
    if the node doesn't exist yet:
      make reactant node
  if there is a product in the reaction:
    make reaction-starting "pseudo node"
    make reaction-ending "pseudo node"
    make link between "pseudo nodes"
    for every reactant:
      make link between reactant and reaction-starting "pseudo node"
    for every product:
      make link between product and reaction-ending "pseudo node"
      if the node doesn't exist yet:
        make product node
```

"all_reactions" is a separate data frame I created from my original dataset because I wanted a different data structure to the original one. In the bit of code I use to verify my numbers I loop through the original dataset to see how many times a compound's ID occurs in all the reactions. Please let me know if more detail is needed and thank you in advance for any help!

[image: Here is a rough diagram of what I mean by reactants, products and "pseudo nodes"]

Comment: I suspect the non-mathematical terminology here is going to make it hard to help.  Can you remove it?  As I understand it, you have a bunch of nodes.  Do we know how many?  Some (all?) of these nodes have certain known properties and based on those properties you may wish to construct edges between them.  Close enough?   Can you phrase the exact question in this language?  Or if, as likely, my stripped down description is missing something, can you phrase the missing piece similarly?

Comment: Hi, lulu. Apologies for the terminology, I'm afraid I don't know any mathematical terminology so I'm trying to explain my problem the best I can. :) I can have up to 2980 nodes, not counting the "pseudo nodes". The nodes represent the compounds in the chemical reactions I'm trying to model. They all have a property for the construction of an edge depending on whether they participate in a reaction or not. When I calculate how many times a compound participates in a reaction I get a number which should be the number of edges but my graph somehow contains more when produced with the above code.

Comment: Not seeking a mathematical phrasing, just a non-chemical one.  Your comment helps.  So I have a reaction, or possibly several reactions (?), and if two nodes are both in the same reaction, I add an edge.  Is that it?  If nodes $n_1, n_2$ are both in the first reaction, but only $n_1$ is in the second, do we add an edge between them or not?  If both are in both, do we add two edges or does your graph avoid such loops?  Is there any other way to get an edge?

Comment: Can we go reaction by reaction or does one reaction change how we interpret another?  If you can go one at a time, I'd check the code that way.  It should be fairly easy to compute the number of edges by hand in that case.  I'm sure it gets very messy once you have lots of reactions.

Comment: Are you excluding the link between the reaction-starting and reaction-ending nodes from your count?

Comment: @lulu It goes reaction by reaction and one reaction doesn't change another. If n1 and n2 are reactants in a reaction they are not connected to each other, they get connected to an invisible "pseudo node" to signify the reaction has "started". I then connect two invisible nodes with a link to show the reaction is "ongoing" and finally when it "ended" I connect the invisible node to the products. I'm not sure how well I'm explaining this, I apologise.

Comment: BTW, if the links you are making have a direction to them (i.e. one of its two nodes is a from-node, the other a to-node), then you don't need to use two linked "pseudo-nodes" for each reaction. You can then have just one node representing the reaction, and distinguish its reactants from its products by the direction of its edges.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Hi, yes I am excluding it.

Comment: I think this is very unclear, sorry.  In the end, I have nodes and edges.  There aren't any pseudo-nodes in the final picture, right?  These are just convenient fictions you have introduced as part of your algorithm (or am I misunderstanding?).  Say we have just one reaction.  How can I tell if $n_1, n_2$ form an edge as a result of that one reaction?

Comment: When you observe errors in the count, are they biased?  That is, does your algorithm always under or over count or is it more like noise?

Comment: Pseudo-nodes are just where edges meet if I have two reactants that participate in a reaction. If I have just one reactant and one product there is nothing showing. They are not part of the original dataset per se but they are inferred when two compounds "join up".

Comment: The count is always under**. Apologies, edited later.

Comment: Well, I don't get it.  Perhaps others will.  Given that the count is always under, I suggest finding some true edges your code missed.    Perhaps there will be an obvious pattern to these.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, @lulu

Comment: What happens if there are two different reactions, but they share both a reactant $r$ and a product $p$? In the graph with the extra nodes representing the reactions there will be two paths from $r$ to $p$, involving $4$ edges that we are counting. In the thing you are comparing it to, would that also count as $4$ - two uses of the reactant and two uses of the product?

Comment: Yes, it would count as 4. This is because my original dataset just has a list of the reactions and the reactions each have a list of reactants and products so if the reactant and product occur together in different reactions they will still form additional edges. At least this is how I intended it to work.